# Loop to read all excel files from sharepoint in R

Tags: r

I want to build a loop to read all excel files in a sharepoint folder. I am using the following code, but it shows that the path does not exist:

```
Filelist <- list.files(path='//XXXcom.sharepoint.com/sites/Shared Documents/General/Email', pattern="*.xlsx")

DF <- lapply(filelist, function(i) {
 L <- read_excel(i, sheet="sheet1")})
```

When I apply to individual excel file, the path works; However, when I apply to the folder, it shows me that path does not exist. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: maybe need setwd() and set file path to where the files are stored

Comment: @Song you have called your files `Filelist` but then run `lapply` with `filelist`. Remember variable names are case sensitive.